# What do I have to consider when sharing the package cache between LXC guests?

Tags: apt

I'd like to bind-mount a single copy of the package cache into all of my LXC guests. They already share a single `apt-cacher-ng` instance on their host. They obviously share the architecture and in fact they are the exact same distro version.

What do I have to consider when I want to do this? Would it be sufficient to ensure that the package cache update doesn't happen in parallel?

Comment: What would be the problem? Isn't that the whole point of apt-cacher?

Comment: @Gilles: several things. With "only" 20 LXC guests the I/O overhead is already tremendous. The Linux kernel is fairly good at caching file system requests. So if I can share stuff at the file system level this should be far superior to the `apt-cacher-ng`. I'd still not want to share between host and guests for other reasons, so the `apt-cacher-ng` instance would be kept for that reason alone. And I believe the point of `apt-cacher-ng` is to download stuff once for many machines. But I want to save on actual disk I/O.

Answer (score 2):

You can share `/var/cache/apt/archives` (or whatever you set `Dir::Cache::pkgcache` to) between Debian installations. I've done that to share the directory between a 32-bit installation and a 64-bit one, or between stable, unstable and testing. However, you probably can't do it usefully, because APT takes a lock on the directory while any upgrade operation is in progress. This means that you wouldn't be able to run `apt-get install` or `apt-get upgrade` in two containers at the same time.

It *may* be safe to break APT's lock if you're sure it doesn't need to download anything. But if you're going down that route, a way to share downloaded files is probably more reliable.

Maybe you could keep apt-cacher-ng as a proxy, and have an incron job that watches for new downloaded packages files and hard links them into every guest's cache directory.